# (React/Material-ui)center text inside paper component in material-ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have been trying to center text inside paper component in material ui and currently nothing works.
I tried to use display:flex in parent component and align-items:center in child component, and I tried to use padding:5px to get equal padding and it didn't work, and absolutely tried text-align and vertical-align and all didn't work
here's what it currently looks like:
[image]

I am trying to center that text in the three bottom boxes(paper components in material-ui)

https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-snowflake-grvxg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I added `justifyContent: center` to the paper class and used Typography component `<Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">` instead of `span` and it seems to work on separate window in codesandbox

Comment: @apocalypsenow please share the link or make an answer so I could check it as the correct one for the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the paper class

```
  paper: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    textAlign: "center",
    verticalAlign: "middle"
    boxShadow: "4px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)",
    borderRadius: "25px",
  },
```

and wrap your questions like so

```
       <Paper className={classes.paper}>
             <Typography
                // style={{ width: "70%", margin: "auto" }} I think you should avoid break tags instead do something with the width
                variant="body2"
                color="textPrimary"
                component="span"
              >
                What are Tabaani experience standards and requirements?
              </Typography>
            </Paper>
```

why you should avoid break tags [here](https://www.tempertemper.net/blog/the-right-way-to-use-break-tags-in-html). And this is my working example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-villani-onswt?file=/src/App.js:4097-4387). Cheers